# Emulate Excel AverageIFs with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to emulate Excel's AVERAGEIFs function in Pandas on a date range, and so far have been unsuccessful.  I understand that I need to use apply and groupby, but I obviously don't have the syntax correct as I receive this error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "Timedelta") to list
```

I am using test data at the moment while I try to figure out the syntax, and the data is below:

[image]

For each 'Avg' column I am trying to return the average quantity for the previous 180 days as grouped by 'A' and 'B'.  Therefore, I would expect the 'Avg' column in row 1 to be 1.5 ( (1+2)/2, while leaving out row 5 which is a match but is > 180 days prior).

Here is the code I have at present, which does not work:
import pandas as pd

```
#Importing the dataset
df = pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(columns=['Avg Qty'])], axis=1)
df['Avg Qty'] = df.apply(df.groupby([(['Date'] <= (['Date']+pd.Timedelta(-1, 
    unit='d')) >= (['Date']+pd.Timedelta(-180, unit='d'))), 'A', 'B']))['Qty'].mean()

print(df.head)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what the first condition is doing, but it certainly isn't right. Do you mind clarifying the intent of this code? Many of us don't know excel, who even knows what an AVERAGEIF does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, I think you want something like this:

```
df['Avg Qty'] = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='180D', key='Date'),'A','B'])['Qty']
                   .transform('mean'))
```

Output:

```
        Date       A         B  Qty  Cost  Avg Qty
0 2017-12-11  Cancer      Golf    1   100      1.5
1 2017-11-11  Cancer      Golf    2   200      1.5
2 2017-11-11  Cardio      Golf    2   300      2.0
3 2017-10-11  Cardio  Baseball    3   600      3.0
4 2017-04-11  Cancer      Golf    4   150      4.0
5 2016-01-01  Cancer  Football    5   200      5.0
```

#### Edit:

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
df.groupby(['A','B']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_index().rolling('180D')['Qty'].mean()).reset_index()\
   .merge(df.reset_index(), on=['Date','A','B'], suffixes=('_avg',''))
```

Output:

```
        A         B       Date  Qty_avg  Qty  Cost
0  Cancer  Football 2016-01-01      5.0    5   200
1  Cancer      Golf 2017-04-11      4.0    4   150
2  Cancer      Golf 2017-11-11      2.0    2   200
3  Cancer      Golf 2017-12-11      1.5    1   100
4  Cardio  Baseball 2017-10-11      3.0    3   600
5  Cardio      Golf 2017-11-11      2.0    2   300
```

Comment: Thank you!  The only point of clarification would be on the result in the second row.  I am looking for the average of the _previous_ 180 days, and the result in the second row would seem to include the first row quantity as well.

Comment: I read through the Grouper documentation, and it appears as though the first two rows aren't working as expected because the frequency parameter lumps 12/11 and 11/11 into the same 180 day period, as opposed to those being rolling averages.  Any thoughts on how to make the "Avg Qty" column a rolling average as opposed to a timeblock average?

Comment: @battery514 Give that a try

Comment: Great!  Happy coding @battery514.